# Entity Framework JSON Search with NpgSql

Tags: json, entity-framework, npgsql

I have an Entity Framework model class like below and as you see it is used with Postgres.

```
[Table]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid DisplayName { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to search an array of string in the column "Tags" I encounter several exceptions like

- npgsql operator does not exist: jsonb && jsonb
- query could not be translated (I tried `EF.Functions.JsonExistsAny` and etc.)

Data structure in the column is like `["apple", "banana", "melon", "grape"]` as JSON

I am trying to search rows that are containing `["apple", "melon"]`

My query is

```
var searchItems = new string[] { "apple", "melon" };
var option1 = dbContext.Users.Where(t => searchItem.Any(a => t.Tags.Contains(a))).ToList();
var option2 = dbContext.Users.Where(t => searchItem.Any(a => EF.Functions.JsonExistAny(a.Tags,)).ToList();
```

I tried to write various queries but stuck with it. Do you see any weird thing?

Comment: The recommended way to map a list of strings for PostgreSQL is simply as a PostgreSQL array (rather than as a jsonb column containing an array). That should be doable by simply removing the [Column] annotation (array mapping is the default). Any particular reason you're not doing that?